# Moving the cursor to the beginning of UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

Is there a way to make the cursor be at the start of a `UITextField`?

When I display the control with content, the cursor is placed at the end of the text. I'd like to move it to the beginning.

Answer (score 19):

`UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol, which provides methods that let you control the selected range.  This works in my testing:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.selectedTextRange = [textField
        textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
        toPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument];
}
```

Comment: This solution works great ! Make sure you conform to UITextField delegate protocol. :)

Answer (score 8):

You're fighting the system on this one. `UITextField` does not have any public properties to set the cursor position (which actually correlates to the beginning of the current selection). If you can use a `UITextView` instead, the following delegate methods will force the cursor to the beginning of the text. Just be aware that users won't expect this behavior and you should double-check your motives for wanting to do it.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    shouldMoveCursor = YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    if(shouldMoveCursor)
    {
        NSRange beginningRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
        NSRange currentRange = [textView selectedRange];
        if(!NSEqualRanges(beginningRange, currentRange))
            [textView setSelectedRange:beginningRange];
        shouldMoveCursor = NO;
    }
}
```

Where `shouldMoveCursor` is a `BOOL` variable you maintain in your controller.

Comment: Hey warrenm, thaks buddy. This code is just awesome man. Hats off to you.

Answer (score 1):

works for me

```
// Get current selected range , this example assumes is an insertion point or empty selection
UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];
// Calculate the new position, - for left and + for right
UITextPosition *newPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:3];
// Construct a new range using the object that adopts the UITextInput, our textfield
UITextRange *newRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newPosition toPosition:newPosition];
// Set new range
[textField setSelectedTextRange:newRange];
```