# Move cursor of text field to beginning

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I am having trouble moving the cursor in a field I populate with data to the beginning of the text field. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468454/moving-cursor-at-beginning-uitextview) and [another like it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180263/moving-the-cursor-to-the-beginning-of-uitextfield) I thought would give me the answer, however, when I create the textfield the app crashes. I am trying to do this for an alert view with a textfield if that makes a difference.

Here is the code sample:

```
var alertView = new UIAlertView("Enter Address:", "", null, "Cancel", "Okay");
alertView.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
alertView.Clicked += AlertView_Clicked;
alertView.GetTextField(0).Text = Address;
var beginning = alertView.GetTextField(0).BeginningOfDocument;
alertView.GetTextField.SelectedTextRange = alertView.GetTextField(0).GetTextRange(beginning, beginning);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to post questions on xamarin Forums,because xamarin community remain active there 24/7; link below :)

http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/ios