# UITextView not putting caret at the start of the textbox

Tags: iphone

For some reason when I click inside the UITextView it starts in the middle. I want the caret to be placed at the beginning of the UITextView control.

Comment: Please provide code with what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180263/moving-the-cursor-to-the-beginning-of-uitextfield

Comment: I have not tried anything! I assume that when I create a UITextView then the cursor should start at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like text alignment is set to center instead of left-justified. If you created the UITextView in a nib, open the nib in Xcode, select the UITextView, select the attributes inspector in the right column of Xcode, and scroll down to the Alignment setting. You will see a control with three segments. Make sure the left segment (left-justified) is selected.